# problem with output of this code

Tags: php

i wrote this code.
in this code we user guess a number then program checked the number with the number that i gite to it and print appropriates message.
 when i start program it shows welcome that is true but when i entered number in it always it shows little in output but it isn't true.

```
   $val = '42';
$gues ;
if(!isset($gues))
$mess =  "welcome<br>";
elseif($gues > $val)
$mess =  "bigr<br>";
elseif($gues < $val)
$mess =  "little<br>";
else
$mess =  "win<br>";

$gues = @(int) $gues;



?>
<html>
<head><title>bazi riazi</title></head> 
<body>
<h1>
<?php print $mess;
?>
</h1>
<form method="POST">
type you gues here:<input type="text" name='gues'>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How your var `$gues` get value from form? Did you use `$_POST['gues']` first?

Script always print `little` because probably variable `$gues` was not initialized any value (default is zero, I suppose...).

Comment: try replace ` $gues ;` with  `$gues = $_POST['gues'];`

Answer (score 0):

This code should work (untested, though):

```
   $val = '42';
   $gues = int($_POST['gues']);

   if (!isset($gues))
   {
       $mess =  "welcome<br>";
   }
   elseif($gues > $val)
   {
       $mess =  "bigr<br>";
   }
   elseif($gues < $val)
   {
       $mess =  "little<br>";
   }
   else
   {
       $mess =  "win<br>";
   }
```